# Lucene.net folder search

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I am newbie in Lucene.net. I want to search a content from the folder which may have all type of files (.txt, .xls, .pdf, .exe, .ppt, .doc,...).

Suppose if I search any content, I want to list the filepath & content matched (it should be highlighted) inside the file if any.

Any sample code would be appreciated.

Note : I am want to use this result in C# class library.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but you should look into using SOLR. AFAIK you cannot host it on a .NET server, but you can connect to it from .NET using [solrSHARP](http://solrsharp.codeplex.com/).